# Why doesn't the value of $input_word become the value of $output_word?

Tags: php

Working on a tutorial by Epicodus. Wondering why the value of the variable $input_word does not change because of strrev($input_word);

```
$input_word = "stressed";
> $output_word = strrev($input_word);
> echo $input_word . " reversed is " . $output_word;
"stressed reversed is desserts"
```

Comment: Who says it has to change? The documentation of [`strrev()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) clearly says it gets a string (and not by reference) and returns another string (the reverse of the input string).

Comment: Because `strrev` *returns* the reversed string, it doesn't change the string *in place.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most PHP functions do not change the values of their arguments. This also applies to most if not all [string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php).

The documentation of [`strrev()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) describes it as:

> string strrev ( string $string )

This means the function receives a string argument (named `$string`) and returns a string. It receives a copy of the string (variable, constant or string literal) passed as argument and it's not able to change the original (constants and literals cannot be changed anyway).

In order to be able to change the value of one of its arguments, a function needs to get it [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). An argument whose value is passed by reference is described in the function's documentation using the reference  sign (`&`).

For example, the array function [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) is described as:

> bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )

Please note the reference sign (`&`) in front of the first argument (`$array`). This function modifies the value of `$array`.

*(The square brackets around the second argument (`$sort_flags`) tells that it is optional.)*

Answer (score 3):

The [strrev](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strrev.php) method does not modify the input parameter.

It return the reversed chain without modifying the input var, This is by design.